# Continue’ button on checkout page in opencart does not works

Tags: opencart, checkout

Button "continue" on checkout page under delivery details doesn't work, but The ‘billing details’ continue button and other always seems to work. When click on the button, the waiting GIF is loaded and nothing happen.

Comment: Possibly not got Fancybox is my guess. Firebug debug it and see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you do not have FancyBox. No dought you are using 1.5v and you are getting jQuery bugs. Check Firebug I am sure it will confirm. Just download and put Fancybox in.

**1) Download FancyBox**

(http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license)

**2) Upload after extracting to:**

www.yoursite.com/fancybox
(just leave it in the root or a CDN)

**3) Open**

*opencart>catalog>view>theme>default>template>common>header.tpl*

or if you have your javascript libraries in footer:

*opencart>catalog>view>theme>default>template>common>footer.tpl*

Add after common.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.0.6"></script>
```